# VB6 upon loading converts adodc to pictureBox

Tags: vb6

Setup windows 10 running and compiling vb6 for our product.

Haven't had issues until recently and my handling of git caused some errors so I had to reload things in from our original copy on another machine.

The issue lies within the form section of my project and I have finally discovered what is causing the issue.

The original issue was though I had the proper components and references loaded in and i could see it in my object browser it failed to use it and gave me the error: `method or data member not found`

After tons of searching I found out the it was converting

what was suppose to be an adodc into a picture box

```
            Height          =   375
            Left            =   -63480
            Top             =   480
            Visible         =   0   'False
            Width           =   1200
            _ExtentX        =   2117
            _ExtentY        =   661
            ConnectMode     =   0
            CursorLocation  =   3
            IsolationLevel  =   -1
            ConnectionTimeout=   240
            CommandTimeout  =   240
            CursorType      =   2
            LockType        =   3
            CommandType     =   1
            CursorOptions   =   0
            CacheSize       =   50
            MaxRecords      =   0
            BOFAction       =   0
            EOFAction       =   0
            ConnectStringType=   1
            Appearance      =   1
            BackColor       =   -2147483643
            ForeColor       =   -2147483640
            Orientation     =   0
            Enabled         =   -1
            Connect         =   ""
            OLEDBString     =   ""
            OLEDBFile       =   ""
            DataSourceName  =   ""
            OtherAttributes =   ""
            UserName        =   ""
            Password        =   ""
            RecordSource    =   $"frmDP.frx":0EAA
            Caption         =   "Adodc1"
            BeginProperty Font {0BE35203-8F91-11CE-9DE3-00AA004BB851} 
               Name            =   "MS Sans Serif"
               Size            =   8.25
               Charset         =   0
               Weight          =   400
               Underline       =   0   'False
               Italic          =   0   'False
               Strikethrough   =   0   'False
            EndProperty
            _Version        =   393216
         End
```

However when you open up the project it labels this as well as at least I've found ```TrueOleDBGrid80.TDBGrid````

to also be labeled and properties set as a pictureBox

I've verified i have the libraries on my machine and are registered.
I've made sure the components and references that are required to use these are also choosen and applied

```
Reference=*\G{6B263850-900B-11D0-9484-00A0C91110ED}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWow64\msstdfmt.dll#Microsoft Data Formatting Object Library 6.0 (SP4)
Reference=*\G{00000206-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}#2.6#0#..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado26.tlb#Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.6 Library
Reference=*\G{3D5C6BF0-69A3-11D0-B393-00A0C9055D8E}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\designer\msderun.dll#Microsoft Data Environment Instance 1.0 (SP4)
Reference=*\G{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}#1.0#0#..\..\..\..\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll#Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Reference=*\G{00025E01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}#5.0#0#..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll#Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
Object={831FDD16-0C5C-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; mscomctl.ocx
Object={67397AA1-7FB1-11D0-B148-00A0C922E820}#6.0#0; MSADODC.OCX
Object={CDE57A40-8B86-11D0-B3C6-00A0C90AEA82}#1.0#0; msdatgrd.ocx
Object={C932BA88-4374-101B-A56C-00AA003668DC}#1.1#0; msmask32.ocx
Object={F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.2#0; ComDlg32.ocx
Object={3B7C8863-D78F-101B-B9B5-04021C009402}#1.2#0; richtx32.ocx
Object={248DD890-BB45-11CF-9ABC-0080C7E7B78D}#1.0#0; mswinsck.ocx
Object={86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; mscomct2.ocx
Object={BDC217C8-ED16-11CD-956C-0000C04E4C0A}#1.1#0; TABCTL32.ocx
Object={E7BC34A0-BA86-11CF-84B1-CBC2DA68BF6C}#1.0#0; ntsvc.ocx
Object={562E3E04-2C31-4ECE-83F4-4017EEE51D40}#8.0#0; todg8.ocx
```

I can manually recreate it though I did not make this myself and more so was put into this section and have had to dig a lot to understand a lot of these things.

The answer i am trying to find is why aren't these being created the way theyre coded to be created.
Or how can i convert these over and have vb6 fix it itself/

Comment: iirc if you open a project with an ocx component that cannot be loaded by the IDE it uses a picture box as a "placeholder" control, if you then re-save the project the picture box remains.  What happens if you delete the picture box and re-add the correct controls from the toolbox?

Comment: Thanks and i was able to get past this with some form of modifying. I just forgot what exactly. Then it didnt recognize any dll's but the were all listed properly in references and components. Some how I fixed that so im nearly fixed with this issue just one more control issue or itemBox issue. Appreciate that info though i didnt know it did that